# eBay API GetOrders createTimeTo & createTimeFrom

Tags: c#, ebay-api

I'm a bit stuck on this one and can't seem to figure it out. I am calling the GetOrders request via the eBay API. The issue is with the `createTimeTo` and `createTimeFrom` inputs.

Currently the way I am handling things is as follows: `CreateTimeFrom = order.CreatedTime` of latest processed order from the last time GetOrders was called + 1 second. I set the `createTimeTo` value to the current ebay official time.

Now this seems to be working fine however I was concerned because when I have things on the production server, is it possible there could be multiple orders at the same second? Because if so then I would be missing orders.

Now I know there are guidelines on the custhelp page for `getOrders`. I tried following them but I am finding it hard to apply the logic to my application.

The guidelines on the customer help page are as follows:

> set "Create / Mod TimeFrom" to the last time you made the call minus 2 minutes.  You are going back 2 mins to ensure that no orders are missed.
>   set "Create / Mod TimeTo" time to the current time minus 2 minutes.  You are going back to ensure that you do not pick up any orders that are still in the process of being completed.

Based on the above logic I am a bit confused with the second point (createTimeto), I am only retrieving completed sales so do I really need to go back 2 mins? Will there be any issue with just having CreateTimeTo as the current eBay official time? Will this method miss any orders for any reason?

Also should I base my createTimeTo and CreateTimeFrom values on the Ebay server timing as if I base it on local timing the local timing could be inconsistent with eBay server times which is what all orders are based on...

How are others handling this?

I have noticed some people use the NumberOfDays property as an alternative to dealing with dates, does anyone know of any advantages of that method?

Answer (score -1):

Using Ebay times would be best. If you can you should. You can use the results of GetEbayTime to Sync your clock.

The 2 minutes at the end, is to help with the deferred/distributed nature of Ebay's processing of Orders. (Speculation). It appears that you may get an Order that is not completed fully. Following the overlaps in the guidlines will help to prevent this issue.

Another way to prevent duplicates is to perform a check on the returned Ebay TransactionId-OrderId. Use a database of some sort.

Or for your specific concern, Keep a list of the Id's returned in the last GetOrder call, and load that list the next time. And check against that. (Your question only asks about the most recent orders).

See: [GetOrders Best Practices](https://ebaydts.com/eBayKBDetails?KBid=5024)

Re: NumberofDays, This is just a convenience. It was added at the same time as the Date filters. ( #691 2010-10-14). Use it if you want.

**Finally**: Refer to the [Ebay's GetOrder Documention](http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/XML/docs/Reference/eBay/GetOrders.html) for these types of things.

Comment: Would the Down-voter be kind enough to give suggestions for improvement?